# Changing column lengths in DBT Oracle

Tags: oracle, dbt

I would like to change the length of a varchar2 column to set it to be 60 characters long. In normal Oracle SQL this would be done using an alter table statement, however I cannot see how to add an alter table statement when using DBT. Is this how it should be done or is there another way?